# retirar details preview do krajee avatar upload?

Tags: jquery, file-upload

Estou a usar o plugin do jquery krajee para fazer upload de imagens, no entanto tenho um problema.
Não consigo remover o botão de zoom da imagem depois do upload

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este è o codigo script de configuração:

```
        <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- the main fileinput plugin file -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/theme.js"></script>


    <!-- the fileinput plugin initialization -->
    <script>
    var btnCust = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" title="Upload">' + 
        '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>'+
        '</button>'; 
    $("#avatar-1").fileinput({
        browseOnZoneClick: true,
        overwriteInitial: true,
        maxFileSize: 1500,
        showClose: false,
        showCaption: false,
        showBrowse: false,
        removeLabel: '',
        removeIcon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>',
        removeTitle: 'Cancel or reset changes',
        elErrorContainer: '#kv-avatar-errors-1',
        msgErrorClass: 'alert alert-block alert-danger',
        defaultPreviewContent: '<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?><?php echo $_SESSION['Utilizador']['Imagem'] ?>" alt="Imagem de perfil" style="width:160px"><h6 class="text-muted">Clique para selecionar</h6>',
        layoutTemplates: {main2: '{preview} ' +  btnCust + ' {remove} {browse}'},
        allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif"]
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Consegue colocar o link desse template no plugin, convém ver o código, porque em ultimo caso temos de usar jquery para remover o botão

Comment: eu vou por aqui em comentário o link do site http://plugins.krajee.com/file-avatar-upload-demo

Comment: Este é para o upload de imagens para perfil mas é exatamente para esse que eu preciso e tem o mesmo problema do botão zoom

Comment: tem sim tente adicionar uma imagem e depois ele aparece para ver a imagem mais detalhada